# When to use RegExp constructor vs regular expression literal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm aware of the differences between using a RegExp constructor and a regular expression literal, but is the use of one versus the other just a matter of preference?

Or are there instances where one *should* use the RegExp constructor versus a regular expression literal? If so, is there an example of this?

Comment: When you are dynamically creating a regex, use the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression when the script is loaded. When the regular expression will remain constant, use this for better performance.
>
> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

In practice, I use the literal form for simple regular expressions.  For more complex expressions, I put them together piece-wise with string concatenation and use the constructor.

**BONUS**: For those complicated regular expressions, a tool like [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) really helps.